# Jquery fade in logo on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I currently have the following simple jQuery script up and running on my site and it's working great, but I'm wanting to add an animation fade in/out to it. I'm just not fluent enough in jQuery to know where to begin with this. Any help would be great! Working example can be seen here, http://staging.biggermarkets.com

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 380) {
    $('.logo').css("opacity", 1);
}
else{
    $('.logo').css("opacity", .1);
}
});
```

Comment: use  $('.logo').fadein("slow")
 $('.logo').fadeout("slow").
to work fadein element should be hidden

Comment: make sure to add .stop() so that you don't have a yoyo effect going on in case the user scrolls up and down very quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fadeTo` to change the opacity over a given period of time, if the opacity should be >0 or just `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` if going between 0 and 1 opacity.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var logo = $('.logo');
  var w = $(window);
  if(w.scrollTop() > 350){
    logo.stop(true, false).fadeTo(500, 1.0);
  } else if(w.scrollTop() < 350) {
    logo.stop(true, false).fadeTo(500, 0.1);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is definitely what I'm trying to accomplish, but it's not quite working properly. The fadeTo is beginning immediately after scrolling instead of waiting to start at the 380px mark and it does not fade back to 10% upon scrolling back up. Any ideas?

Comment: @StevenJones the answer of james is working very well. Which part is not clear?

Comment: @StevenJones because fadeIn takes time.

Comment: @codingfreak If you take a look at staging.biggermarkets.com you'll notice that the fadeTo starts upon first scroll instead of starting once you pass 380px from .scrollTop. Also when you scroll back up, the logo does not return to it's original opacity which should be 10%.

Comment: @StevenJones I think the question is already answered so please come to my Skype ali.carikcioglu3 so we can discuss particularly about your website.

Comment: Looks like it is working, but it's taking approximately 5 seconds for the fade to start once the target area is reached. Any way to make the fadeTo start immediately once a user scrolls past 380px? Notice how quickly the fadeIn works on our old site, biggermarkets.com. This is what I'm trying to accomplish but wanting the logo to start at 10% opacity instead of 0

Comment: Steven, I have updated my answer with improved code. The lag issue you were experiencing was probably because the original code snippet didn't make use of `stop`, which clears any animations queued up for a given element. The `scroll` event fires for every pixel scrolled, so we were queuing up a `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` animation for every pixel moved - not very efficient! With the new code, we still queue up an animation for every pixel moved, but we clear any previous ones as we add them. It could be further improved, but give the new code a try and see how it feels.

Comment: Perfect! That works exactly how I envisioned it. Thanks James!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.logo').fadeIn()
```

[Fade in documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/).